# Building opendaylight from source

Tags: opendaylight, ubuntu-17.10

I am new to ODL and am trying to install the carbon release using the source code mentioned in 
[this website](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:Pulling,_Hacking,_and_Pushing_the_Code_from_the_CLI#Build_the_code)
I somehow only get different folders inside the opendaylight folder than      'opendaylight/distribution/opendaylight/'.
Can someone guide me through how to build ODL from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions are way out-of-date. That was back from the first release when mostly everything was in one git project, controller. Now the code is spread out in many different git projects so it depends which part you want to build. If you want to build the openflow code then git clone the openflowplugin project and 'mvn -Pq install' from the top level.

Comment: Thank you! I tried 'mvn -DskipTests install' from root , I got an error : non-readable settings /root/.m2/settings.xml: input contained no data @root/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: well, is your /root/.m2/settings.xml file readable? ;-) Hope you saw here how to get the custom settings.xml required by ODL, on https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:Development_Environment_Setup#Edit_your_.7E.2F.m2.2Fsettings.xml ? [And why do you run as root user instead of a regular user?]

Comment: @vorburger : Should I also clone the odlparent project?

Comment: @sushmitadas no the dependencies which one ODL project has on other projects, including odlparent, get downloaded from nexus.opendaylight.org.